Unable to update Android 8.0.0 to a higher version
I have an older version of Android and I want to update to a later version, version 10 or higher. I went to Settings > System > System updates and got a message 'Checking for updates...' but it does not allow me to update to a later version, instead it says 'Done' rather than offering any updates. Does anyone know why this is and how you can fix this? From my research I have found that there are ways to manually force an update, but I am unsure that is the best option because my phone may not be able to update to higher versions due to insufficient storage space or other reasons.

Please [edit] to add your device details (also on the tags) // Every device has an update support cycle beyond which you won't get updates of any kind (security patches/Android updates). That could be the case with your device, though admittedly Done on the UI is vague// see this answer for other ways of updating, some of the needing to root your device and in the process wipe data

Android 8 is six versions behind the latest and no OEM would be providing version updates over 6 years (Pixel started supporting for 7 years starting last year) , so the link in comment is your way out apart from buying a new device

See also How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version
